# Reduce the HTTP Requests of 1000 images?

Tags: image, http, request, reduce

I know this question might sound a little bit crazy, but I tough that maybe someone could come up with a smart idea:

Imagine you have 1000 thumbnail images on a single HTML page.

The image size is about 5-10 kb.

Is there a way to load all images in a single request? Somehow zip all images into a single file…

Or do you have any other suggestions in the subject?

**Other options I already know of:**

CSS sprites

Lazy load

Set Expire headers

Downloads images across different hostnames

Comment: You could make a composite image using gd?

Comment: why they have to in ONE page? why not use CSS sprites?

Comment: I think I would try CSS sprites with one big progressive JPG.

Comment: Thanks mootinator havn’t, heard of GD before. Will check it out. Are you shore it’s possible to load all images in one single http request using GD, or is it for something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have a "JavaScript search function". That's one reason I want them on a single page. I also have a JavaScript resize function. That’s why I can’t use Sprites. Also there will be a lot of work updating the sprites (to technical for end customer).

Comment: Found this. You can do this in flash (and silverlight):
http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/ You can do it by using Javascript (it’s slow) http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/read-load-files-from-zip-in-javascript/ But there just must be some other way! Will give it some more hours. Please comment if you have any ideas!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for: http://limi.net/articles/resource-packages/. Does anybody know where to find more information about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only two other options I can think of given your situation:

1. Use the "data:" protocol and echo a base64 encoded version of your thumbnails directly into the HTML page.  I would not recommend this since you cannot then cache those images on the users browser.
2. Use HTML5's Web Storage to store all the images as records with the base64 encoded image data stored as BLOBs in a column.  Once the database has downloaded to the users machine, use Javascript to loop through all the records and create the thumbnails on the page dynamically using something like jQuery.  With this option you would need to wait till the entire database was done downloading on the end users browser, and they will need a fairly modern browser.

I think your best bet is a combination of lazy loading, caching with expires headers and serving images from multiple hostnames.

If the images can be grouped logically, CSS sprites may also work for you in addition to everything above.  For example, if your thumbnails are for images uploaded on a certain day...you may be able to create a single file for each day which could then be cached on the users browser.

Comment: Given that it says all the images are on a single page, a sprite is the way to go.

Comment: @ysth, I agree that CSS sprites would likely be beneficial.  If the thumbnails are frequently added to his page, say every day or so, it may be beneficial to group the thumbnails into multiple CSS sprites.  1000 10kb thumbs is 1.22MB.  Adding a new thumbnail to a single, monolithic sprite, would require that the end user download that entire file again, destroying any ability to cache the CSS positions and image data of previously downloaded sprites.  If his page never changes, or changes infrequently, a single CSS sprite may be the best option.

Comment: Thanks John, I agree with the “best bet”. Cache is more important and I guess I will hang myself trying to fix it in IE 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by using what's called a CSS sprite; a single image with all the other images inside it, with the particular part that's wanted in the html selected by css.

See one tutorial at http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites

Comment: Unfortunately Sprites are not an option in this case since the images will be resizeble. Thanks any way.

Comment: @Hakan, Err, what do you mean by "resizeble"?

Comment: Via java script the visitor can change width of all images, to control how many images per row to display...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like SPDY's [server push](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2#TOC-Server-Push-Transactions).  When the client requests the HTML page (or the first image), SPDY allows the server to push the other resources without waiting for more requests.

Of course, this is still experimental.

Comment: Looks very interesting! Will have a look at it tonight, thanks Matthew.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [montage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-montageimage.php) command of imagemagick to create a single image.