# Rendering 4000 Images with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, awesomium

**Can HTML render 4000+ images without the viewport being slow?**

I've been trying to render 4000 images one after the other with only a space to seperate them resized with a fixed height(400px) so that you get a wall of images using HTML.

I always thought it might be Apache slowing it down, but it happens in every single occurnce so far. Apache/Node Webkit. Etc. I'm just wondering if [awesomium](http://awesomium.com) is able to handle that. Since its written in native code. Unfortunantly I don't have the skills nessecary to work with .NET or C++ to test it out.

Could Awesomium render this and have a more responsive viewport or is there some other limitation I don't know about that might be causing this?

**Edit: The images are loaded from the filesystem using either Node.js (Node Webkit), TideSDK, PHP Desktop MSIE/Chrome (Apache). All the images are loaded (almost) instantly, It's the Viewport that is slow. (Scrolling, resizing etc.)**

To clarify even more here is my TideSDK application.

```
<script type="text/php">
include 'functions.php';
$height = 400;
$dirs = glob('H:/images/*.deviantart.net', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($dirs as $dir)
{
    $base = $dir.'/';
    $files = ListIn($base);
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $file = $base.$file;
        $link = "<img src='file:///$file' height='$height' onclick='Ti.Platform.openURL(\"file:///$file\")'> ";
        #$link = "$base$file <br>";
        $document->write($link);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use pagination?

Comment: Just tested it with Chrome, 10k images, still SMOOTH. After the browser caches the images, there will be no problem. We need more information if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The images are loaded from the filesystem using either Node.js (Node Webkit), TideSDK, PHP Desktop MSIE/Chrome. I have not tried this in regular chrome because it does not allow viewing images from the local filesystem. I would have a little trouble finding 10k images remotely, so can you show me your result? I am very interested.

Comment: @user858045 Save a complete webpage to your drive using ctrl+s. Then open the saved html in Chrome. Run Chrome from the command line with some flags to allow loading local filesystem images: `chrome.exe --allow-access-from-files --allow-file-access-from-files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe try it with LazyLoad?

Comment: I didn't really consider this a real answer but recently I revisited this problem and was looking at windows explorer Image Viewing experience noticing that thumbnails had a sort of lazy loading to it. I have also tried this with some basic Jquery Lazy Loading, it works fairly well. It's still slow but mostly because the images are not thumbnails but full images. Which is why I'm going to consider thumbs/caching+lazy loading. I think this answer fits best with my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below given

[Reduce the HTTP Requests of 1000 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543743/reduce-the-http-requests-of-1000-images)

URL may be it will help you